# Can I define tiny templates or functions in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

Sometimes I could make use of simple shortcuts to skip writing lot of HTML manually. For example, I would like to define a template so that instead of this:

```
<img class="big" src="{{site.baseurl}}/images/screenshots/image.png" />
```

I can write this:

```
{image.png | bigscreenshot}
```

Another example. This is what I use for keyboard shortcuts:

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
```

This would be way better:

```
{Ctrl + J | to_shortcut}
```

That would make the code way shorter and that's valuable for me, because I'm writing documentation. Is this somehow possible? It **must** work on GitHub pages.

Comment: "Must work on GH pages". Does it mean that you want to push code and let GH pages generate your site ? Or are you ready to generate locally then push resulting code ?

Comment: I let github process the code. The `_site` folder is in `.gitignore`. My reasoning with this is that when something goes wrong I can edit it in Guthub web UI without initialising git repository on some computer. This means only plugins that are guaranteed to be working on Github pages are acceptable for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to define new tags without plugins.

If you want to completely delegate code generation to gh pages, an alternative can be to use includes.

```
{% include img name="toto" %}
```

**_includes/img**

```
<img class="big" src="{{site.baseurl}}/path/{{ include.name }}.png" />
```

Or `{% include c k="j" %}`

**_includes/c**

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{{ include.k | capitalize }}</kbd>
```